# Java Date Parsing As Per Format

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

I need to parse the date as per format but it didn't work very well.

```
   public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String dateInString = "07/06/2013";
                Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
                System.out.println(date);
            }
        }
```

i need date object in 07/06/2013 format even if date was in any format. but parse method always return in Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 PKT 2013.

Comment: `Date` is nothing more then a container for the number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, it has no format of it's own, that's what `DateFormat` is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always have your date object in "dd/MM/yyyy" format - when you want to output it just use:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

The reason you see Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 PKT 2013 displayed is because `System.out.println` uses the default `toString` representation of the object you provided. For `Date` instances it gives you such information (depending on locale, afaik).

P.S. keep in mind that instances of `SimpleDateFormat` are not thread-safe so it is better to create new ones.

Comment: then what is purpose of parse method in DateFormat?

Comment: You want to use objects as much as possible. In this case `Date` is a (very) good encapsulation for dates - with all their hours, minutes, timestamps and so on. Now imagine your application receives a date formatted as a `String`. You want to convert this to a `Date` object (with the parse method) so that you can manipulate it more easier!

Comment: Think of `parse` as an import and `format` as an export - everybody can deal with `String`s - that is why you "export" your date object and give it to them. Your users want to enter their birthday as a `String` in your application - this is where you "import" it so you can for example calculate how old they are

Comment: so that only way in parsing is by Locale specific formate